# Moved data not sending in php submit

Tags: javascript, php

I'm using the following function to move data between two select fields:

```
<script language="javascript"> 
function move(tbFrom, tbTo) 
{
 var arrFrom = new Array(); var arrTo = new Array(); 
 var arrLU = new Array();
 var i;
 for (i = 0; i < tbTo.options.length; i++) 
 {
  arrLU[tbTo.options[i].text] = tbTo.options[i].value;
  arrTo[i] = tbTo.options[i].text;
 }
 var fLength = 0;
 var tLength = arrTo.length;
 for(i = 0; i < tbFrom.options.length; i++) 
 {
  arrLU[tbFrom.options[i].text] = tbFrom.options[i].value;
  if (tbFrom.options[i].selected && tbFrom.options[i].value != "") 
  {
   arrTo[tLength] = tbFrom.options[i].text;
   tLength++;
  }
  else 
  {
   arrFrom[fLength] = tbFrom.options[i].text;
   fLength++;
  }
}

tbFrom.length = 0;
tbTo.length = 0;
var ii;

for(ii = 0; ii < arrFrom.length; ii++) 
{
  var no = new Option();
  no.value = arrLU[arrFrom[ii]];
  no.text = arrFrom[ii];
  tbFrom[ii] = no;
}

for(ii = 0; ii < arrTo.length; ii++) 
{
 var no = new Option();
 no.value = arrLU[arrTo[ii]];
 no.text = arrTo[ii];
 tbTo[ii] = no;
}
}

</script>
```

main php page

```
<?php
mysql_select_db($database_UARData, $UARData);
$query_DistributionGroups = "SELECT distgrp.distgrpnme FROM distgrp";
$DistributionGroups = mysql_query($query_DistributionGroups, $UARData) or die(mysql_error());
$row_DistributionGroups = mysql_fetch_assoc($DistributionGroups);
$totalRows_DistributionGroups = mysql_num_rows($DistributionGroups);

?>

          <select name="newusrdgavail" size="10" id="newusrdgavail" style="width:300px">
            <?php
do {  
?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row_DistributionGroups['distgrpnme']?>"><?php echo $row_DistributionGroups['distgrpnme']?></option>
            <?php
} while ($row_DistributionGroups = mysql_fetch_assoc($DistributionGroups));
  $rows = mysql_num_rows($DistributionGroups);
  if($rows > 0) {
      mysql_data_seek($DistributionGroups, 0);
      $row_DistributionGroups = mysql_fetch_assoc($DistributionGroups);
  }
?>
          </select>
        </label></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><p>
          <input type="button" name="newusrdgadd" id="newusrdgadd" value="Add" onclick="move(newusrdgavail,newusrdgreq)"/>
        </p>
          <p>
            <input type="button" name="newusrdgremove" id="newusrdgremove" value="Remove" onclick="move(newusrdgreq,newusrdgavail)"/>
          </p></td>
        <td bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><label>
          <select name="newusrdgreq" size="10" multiple="multiple" id="newusrdgreq" style="width:300px">
          </select>
        </label></td>
```

The move function works well and the moved values show in the correct field on the form. The problem is when I go to php submit:

```
$newusrdgreq = $_POST['newusrdgreq'];
$email_message .= "Required Email Distribution Groups: ".$newusrdgreq."\n";
```

I get the Notice: Undefined Index. On this field only. Everything else submits just fine. I know I can use the isset function to avoid empty or null values. However I think the great issue is that the "newusrdgreq" field is not getting the added and removed values properly attached to the field, but I cannot see why. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

problem here that SELECT has only one value, even if you set it `multiple` - user must select all values manually, so basically all you items in select box - are not sending back to server

to fix this you can have 2 options:

1. create hidden field were you will duplicate data from select box
2. before submit - select all values in SELECT

Comment: I think you can mark as selected multiple values if you can't use val() to do it.
`$("select").find("option[value=ONE],option[value=TWO]").prop("selected", true);`

Comment: @IlyaBursov I tried the second item and selected all values in the SELECT however the email only contains the last value. Any further ideas?

Comment: I turned the select into an array and it prints perfectly in php. Just have to expand array so it sends each value in the email